# why is all the text in the body seem to be overlapping onto one line instead of being on new lines

Tags: flutter, dart

[Its an onboarding screen with some body text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2keBv.png)

```
PageViewModel(
      title: "",
        body: "Thousands of\ndoctors & experts to \nhelp your health!",
        footer: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text("Next"),
        ),
        image: Center(child: Image.asset('assets/onboard1.png')),
        decoration: const PageDecoration(
            bodyTextStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Color(0xFF06B4A0),
          fontSize: 40,
          fontFamily: 'Urbanist',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          height: 0.03,
        ))),
```

I already tried to add the body string into a text widget, its not allowed and gives me a "only expected a string?" error.

Answer (score 1):

add line

```
maxLines: 100,
```

into the TextStyle widget.